# Error when using recursive type in a function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a recursive type that extracts the indices from a nested object and puts them in a flat, strongly-typed tuple, like so:

```
type NestedRecord = Record<string, any>

type RecursiveGetIndex<
  TRecord extends NestedRecord,
  TPreviousIndices extends any[] = []
> = {
  [K in keyof TRecord]: TRecord[K] extends NestedRecord
    ? RecursiveGetIndex<
        TRecord[K],
        AppendToTuple<TPreviousIndices,K>
      >
    : AppendToTuple<TPreviousIndices, K>
}[keyof TRecord]

type AppendToTuple<T extends any[], U> = [...T, U]
```

It works fine when called with a concrete instantiation of a nested object type, e.g.:

```
type AnIndex = RecursiveGetIndex<{ foo: { bar: { baz: number}}}>
```

In other words, as expected, `AnIndex` is typed as  `["foo", "bar", "baz"]`

But, when I try to use the Recursive type in a function, I get a recursion error:

```
function doSomething<T extends NestedRecord>(arg:T){
    type Nested = RecursiveGetIndex<T>
    const doMore = (n: Nested) => {
        console.log(n) //Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly nested
    }
}
```

Which kind of makes sense to me because TS doesn't really know how deeply recursed `T` might be.

Is that correct? Why wouldn't TS just wait until it see's how `doSomething` is instantiated before worrying about recursion?

And, is there some way to avoid the error if I know in advance that the `arg` passed to the function will never exceed the TS recursion limit (50, i believe).  I.e., can I somehow tell typescript that?

I've seen solutions that limit recursion basically by using a decrementing array type, e.g. [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68891915/typescript-type-max-recursion-limited-to-9).  Is that the best I can do here?

[Playground with the code.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=2&pln=28&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDOwIBMBKEDGB7ATsqAvFOtngDyI4CWAdgOYA0UAhjSAHwBQnokxmAVxzwqANwgBxCMACSNZBAAeZTlCgAVErnxKk8%20LARI0mbQ1UaACjgiiqWAfDnIqGBFF0R9LNgG0AuoRQAZzsQQDeFr4A0lC0UADWECBYAGYaWnj%20AFwZpngxgZ7ecIgomcgWagD8-BhCIuJSsvJKKmodHZr5yIXmnZ0AgmCQ8upY6gJgADYQZOrWtvaOzq4IDNFcA1BbHbnDo8jjkzNzCzZ2Dk7ya-BMm5wAvr5JKendpMj%203LzQB15HCZTWbzDyKPTIAysEABJgAVTCRF8ADpUep4YFuAB6LEaAAWVAM2BoGBsSCgvwMAHdcAkDKlaBAfuA-jRnEogiQGmJJNJ2cpwlBUlgsLlBQAjZg4MVQSUAL1yNAEAFtxRAcI9NWEcVBBmzWoogr4AETCrDGpjGyU4C1QK3MOXG76cHXqPHQVICEnAew0KCOWh0CnuqA2erCHkUllQPHMKF%209U4XCo5HcT3e31QZBYADKWGV0gJ9FBxUhhjKJk%207AAFFK6Nl1ABKSKdX7l4ycwQRpp8g3zXZqYmILNYACyuGgRGrNFypWMjcIYRb2ygQ6ws2R0ywdGnC5x6mjtEQrB9zB9WD9hLBbngjQg0xAWYgEDAPnwYCwt6o4ofUBoRhQKooEeJ4gA)

### Updated

Per captain-yossarian's suggestion, the following works:

```
type RecursiveGetIndex<
  TRecord extends NestedRecord,
  TPreviousIndices extends any[] = [],
  TDepth extends number = 5
> = 10 extends TPreviousIndices["length"] ? TPreviousIndices : {
  [K in keyof TRecord]: TRecord[K] extends NestedRecord
    ? RecursiveGetIndex<
        TRecord[K],
        AppendToTuple<TPreviousIndices,K>
      >
    : AppendToTuple<TPreviousIndices, K>
}[keyof TRecord]
```

The error recurs, however, if this number is any higher than 10.  I would have thought that should be 50.  Is my type more recursive than I think?

[Updated playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDOwIBMBKEDGB7ATsqAvFOtngDyI4CWAdgOYA0UAhjSAHwBQnokxmAVxzwqANwgBxCMACSNZBAAeZTlCgAVErnxKk8%20LARI0mbQ1UaACjgiiqWAfDnIqGBFF0R9LNgG0AuoRQAeZq6gAiEGDAABYeinrIBjQCALYARhA4QQCsnOxBAIyF8YkG6ta29o7Orgi%20AEQANl50sQ2BAPxWNnYOTvJ1BgBcUADeUAD0kwCiODi4UJlNWADuUKtUTU1QdFgsq8wgUFQAZlCxVAaizE0C0FdQhQAMFr4A0ic0UADWECBYc6aUx4fyjYGkZAfQKebxwRAoLR4CxqbokIQicRSWTyJQqNQEgkQ7TQ0KEgkAQTAkHk6iw6gEYBaZAqvWqAxcbngDHeXHJUD5BNGVJpyDpDKZEBZlT6NUGXKYvM4AF9fH8AUCkch-NxeNARV4xfTGcz1KVDQZWCAQlAAKoFIi%20AB0LvUTFtgW40w0MUe2BoGBsSAu4Hcq1wPwMp1oEF1oagFJoziUQXRwjEkmkyeUE1OWCwowm6WYOELS2YAC9RikMlllfWCt7E9mgo081gGkwGsWcJ2oN3Kx0vZMfdBTgIA8B7N9HLQ6BcYtAbBgMRmQ3wYsxLd8sgscC6ndxx5Pp1BkFgAMpYVLSX30FnmuFGREg5DsAAUJbow3UAEoxii67QPCxipoI6ZYlmuLKOogpqP6iBnlgACyuDQEQ740KMIEoL%20hAFAB-LwVgNDwFgLROisdCYXh0zqPGtCIKwU7MFOJEnAYShcpiEBNMcChRD4%20BgFg8AiOkfFQDQz7IIByoqkAA)

Comment: Here https://catchts.com/recursive-ds you can find recursive type with limitation. As for the second example, TS can't wait untic you call this function because these are two different stages

Comment: blah, recursive types like this are evaluated in a weird/funny way and I don't know of any good way to deal with the problem here.  I haven't found anything great, anyway.

Comment: @captain-yossarian, that's clever.  using that with my code it looks like starting the type with `= 10 extends TPreviousIndices["length"] ? TPreviousIndices : //etc` works, but if i make it 11 it has an error.  is there some reason each level of recursion counts as more than 1 for purposes of TS's limit?

Comment: @sam256 could you please provide an example of how you calling it?

Comment: i'll edit my question so i can fit in the playground link

Comment: @captain-yossarian, question updated. do mapped types count "more" against the recursion limit?

Comment: Honestly, I cant explain it. I think it is better to ask somebody from ts team or search in github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RecursiveGetIndex<NestedRecord>` is the real problem here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDOwIBMBKEDGB7ATsqAvFOtngDyI4CWAdgOYA0UAhjSAHwBQnokxmAVxzwqANwgBxCMACSNZBAAeZTlCgAVErnxKk8+LARI0mbQ1UaACjgiiqWAfDnIqGBFF0R9LNgG0AuoRQAZzsQQDeFr4A0lC0UADWECBYAGYaWnj+AFwZpngxgZ7ecIgomcgWagD8-BhCIuJSsvJKKmodHZr5yIXmnZ0AgmCQ8upY6gJgADYQZOrWtvaOzq4IDNFcA1BbHbnDo8jjkzNzCzZ2Dk7ya-BMm5wAvr5JKendpMj+3LzQB15HCZTWbzDyKPTIAysEABJgAVTCRF8ADpUep4YEfuA-kESA0xJJpM42qVjBV2EA) and this is because of how `any` works for a conditional type.

Since your generic is constrained to `NestedRecord` typescript has to try to apply `RecursiveGetIndex` to the constrain inside the function in order to give you type checking, however this means that `TRecord[K]` is `any` so the condition `TRecord[K] extends NestedRecord` will end up evaluating both branches and since one branch ends up calling `RecursiveGetIndex` again in the same way.

Once `TRecord=any` with your original implementation it just keeps on looking for nested keys forever.  So you can add a check for `any` and resolve to just `...any[]` in that case so it doesn't get caught in infinite recursion. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-NweOBoN6RX7zZb1MLvNz-EwAKphIi+WnqEu8tN8PU0ZWKIIkcYKqSyeQq8I5LDY7tA5rYmgCAC2IJwTAHAC9sYto9GwpxtmoAHqU7jxB4YPZYRHILAAZSwI+kaVodCt+dFcHFJkJ7AAFM06Jj1ABKSLq3jQG9-Igt+VxHbRsrQ9NRsBoRAoH3ABZXBoCIB8aGxX8UDfQgwk-N1zkgrBGhueosDoJD0NiDIbCgREiiOQpcGyZgoEIlJ6ioNYoAeJ4sBeaVoxjTggA)

```
type NestedRecord = Record<string, any>

type RecursiveGetIndex<
  TRecord extends NestedRecord,
  TPreviousIndices extends any[] = []
> = {
   // first check for any with 0 extends <clearly not 0> and opt out of recursing with just any nested keys
   // optionally you could use ...unknown[] if you wanted to be safer.
  [K in keyof TRecord]: 0 extends TRecord[K]&1 ? [...TPreviousIndices, K, ...any[]] 
  : TRecord[K] extends NestedRecord
    ? RecursiveGetIndex<
        TRecord[K],
        AppendToTuple<TPreviousIndices,K>
      >
    : AppendToTuple<TPreviousIndices, K>
}[keyof TRecord]


type AppendToTuple<T extends any[], U> = [...T, U] 

type AnIndex = RecursiveGetIndex<{ foo: { bar: number, baz: any}}> 
//   ^? ["foo", "bar"] | ["foo", "baz", ...any[]]

function doSomething<T extends NestedRecord>(arg:T){
    type Nested = RecursiveGetIndex<T>
    const doMore = (n: Nested) => {
        console.log(n) //here n will work a lot like unknown
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems right to me, in that I do tend to hit these problems when I have an `any` constraint in a conditional type.  But could you explain the 2nd paragraph a little more?  Specifically why is it passing `any` when it hits two levels deep? I'm missing a step there.

Comment: oh, by two levels deep, you mean in the function, not the recursion, correct?

Comment: yeah terminology is hard, I edited to try to be clearer but idk how successful I was. The point is that `any` makes most reasonable recursive types break in annoying ways since it evaluates both branches of conditionals so you often have to explicitly check for it to stop infinite recursion.

Comment: your edits do make it clearer for me.  thanks.  this is one of two tough TS recursion problems in a project i'm working on, which is making me a think i need a non-recursive solution...